# VMINNM instruction in ARM

Tags: arm, armv8

I would like to know how `vminnm` is working. Since the pseudo-code is bit unclear, I am not able to understand what is the exact function of this instruction.

```
vminnm.f32  d3, d5, d13
```

where

```
d5  = 0xffd5432100000000
d13 = 0x7ff0056000000000
```

Result:

```
d3  = 0x7fc0000000000000
```

How we are arriving with this result ?

Comment: According to documentation http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/CIHFCJCF.html, that should calculate the minimum of d3 and d5, and return the result on d13. So, it that has not sense to me.

Comment: I also had the same doubt. But the simulator is showing this result and I am sure simulator is correct.

Comment: Where did you get this pseudo-code? Did you compile and checked the result?
Which simulator did you used? Does it support the Advanced SIMD ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition on the ARM Reference Manual for that instruction.
([**NaN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is *Not a Number*, that means that the value is not a valid floating point number.)

> VMINNM
>
> This instruction determines the floating point minimum number.
> It handles NaNs in consistence with the IEEE754-2008 specification. It returns the numerical operand when one
> operand is numerical and the other is a quiet NaN, but otherwise the result is identical to floating-point VMIN .
> This instruction is not conditional.

```
vminnm.f32  d3, d5, d13
```

In your example, the values in *d5* and *d13* are compared and the result of the comparison is stored in *d3*. Take into consideration that you are dealing with  vectors and you have two elements in each vector, which are 32-bit floating point each.

The value *0xffd5432100000000* is a valid 64-bit double, but not two 32-bit floating point, i.e *0xffd54321* is *not a number* and *0x00000000* is 0, so when you compare these values you need to be aware of the width of the values you are comparing. (You can check the values of floating points [here](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/).)